# Adjust item stock accordingly to checkout carts

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

So in Craft Commerce, we have stock items. What I want is to display items in stock, but adjust it to active checkout charts containing those items.

(only when an active had a checkout or being disband stock must correct itself)

How would it be possible to implement such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I made a workaround, I'm going to use Custom Order Status to manage "in stock" and "pending in cart" and get both the values and make a calculation that will be put in the "stock" value displaying in the front.

Comment: Will you happen to have a technical example of this? It’s an interesting answer, only if you could give an example it would be great!